# magento 2: trigger js form validation without submit

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, form-validation

On a custom frontend page I have a form in which I use magento's js validation to validate inputs: name, email description, etc.  When the form is submitted the validation is triggered and works properly.  I am wondering if there is a way to manually invoke magento's js validation without requiring a "submit" action.

Here is what I use to apply the validation

```
var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
var ignore = null;
dataForm.mage('validation', {
    ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
}).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

and I am looking for

```
$("#form-validate").mageValidate();  // validate form fields
```

Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: I have tried requiring `mage/validation`  and then using `$('#form-validate').validation();` but validation does not seem to be triggered

Answer (score 44, accepted):

was able to figure this out by referencing:

`module-checkout-agreements/view/frontend/web/js/model/agreement-validator.js`

After including `mage/validation` you have to pass argument `isValid` to mage.validation in order to invoke the validation

Full code looks like

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/validation'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = null;

    dataForm.mage('validation', {
        ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
    }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

    $('button#my-button').click( function() { //can be replaced with any event
        dataForm.validation('isValid'); //validates form and returns boolean
    });
});
```

You can also replace argument with `clearError` to remove validation error messages

Comment: it is giving folowing error:   Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on validation prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'isValid'

Comment: try adding `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'` attribute to form, also double check your form selector is correct.

Comment: @Xenocide8998, Thank you so much. It's work.

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-button-name').click(function () { // The button type should be "button" and not submit
            if ($('#form-name').valid()) {
                alert("Validation pass");
                return false;
            }else{
                alert("Validation failed");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: if ($('#form-name').valid())  this is not work for me

Comment: showing error like this jquery.validate.js:111 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

Comment: if($('#form-id').valid() === false){
                return false;
            };

is nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate the Individual field on the blur event then please add the below script in your code.

```
require([
'jquery',
'mage/validation'
], function($){

var dataForm = $('#form-id');
var ignore = null;

dataForm.mage('validation', {
    ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
}).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

$('#form-id input').on('blur', function() {
     // validate  
    $.validator.validateSingleElement($(this));
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check **form validation before submit, Reset the form after submit and clear the validation messages** -

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/validation'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = null;

    dataForm.mage('validation', {
        ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
    }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

    $('button#my-button').click( function() { //can be replaced with any event
        // (Method - 1)
        dataForm.validation('isValid'); //validates form and returns boolean
        // OR (Method - 2)
        if(dataForm.valid()){
            dataForm[0].reset();    // to reset the form 
            dataForm.validation('clearError');      // to remove validation error messages
        }
    });
});
```