# Display validation error on page load on checkout page

Tags: magento2.3.3, validation, onestepcheckout

Is there any way I can display the validation message 'This is a require field' on page load on checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, On the page load trigger click on submit button on current checkout page by jQuery. Then the required field will show the magento default validation messages.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Following Code and try :-

Create the file :

**`NameSpace/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`**

In it, I will insert rules for validation name = '**company**'.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <referenceBlock  name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                                                                            <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">9</item>
                                                                            <item name="letters-only" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="max-words" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="fax" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

How many validation rules Check this :-

```
min_text_length
max_text_length
max-words
min-words
range-words
letters-with-basic-punc
alphanumeric
letters-only
no-whitespace
zip-range
integer
vinUS
dateITA
dateNL
time
time12h
phoneUS
phoneUK
mobileUK
stripped-min-length
email2
url2
credit-card-types
ipv4
ipv6
pattern
validate-no-html-tags
validate-select
validate-no-empty
validate-alphanum-with-spaces
validate-data
validate-street
validate-phoneStrict
validate-phoneLax
validate-fax
validate-email
validate-emailSender
validate-password
validate-admin-password
validate-url
validate-clean-url
validate-xml-identifier
validate-ssn
validate-zip-us
validate-date-au
validate-currency-dollar
validate-not-negative-number
validate-zero-or-greater
validate-greater-than-zero
validate-css-length
validate-number
validate-number-range
validate-digits
validate-digits-range
validate-range
validate-alpha
validate-code
validate-alphanum
validate-date
validate-identifier
validate-zip-international
validate-state
less-than-equals-to
greater-than-equals-to
validate-emails
validate-cc-number
validate-cc-ukss
required-entry
checked
not-negative-amount
validate-per-page-value-list
validate-new-password
validate-item-quantity
equalTo
```

And you want to Get More-information Check this link :-

**[Magento 2.2 Input field validation on Checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227390/magento-2-2-input-field-validation-on-checkout-page)**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: My validation is working good (Upon clicking Place Order button it is displaying). I just need to display the message "This is a require field" on the page load by default.

Comment: check this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/143614/85907. This link is without any button click show validation message.